# PHP mail function, remove the neccessity for errors-to header

Tags: php, email

I'm on a server that requires the errrors-to header to be set when using PHP mail() function. Popular applications such as Wordpress don't specify this header (at least not everywhere) - so the email isn't sent (instead I'm sent a message saying there was an error sending the email because it lacked the header). The server host says this is not something they can change for the system. I do not have access to the .ini file. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: Configure a different smtp [server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php), which does not have this dependency. (Which in turn would be easier with using something other than the mail() function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, by setting the mail-header you need with the normal [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)-function:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'errors-to: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

In wordpress, you can overload the [wp_mail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)-function to include that header.

Comment: I was particularly trying to solve this for Wordpress and this is the perfect solution for that. Thank you.